# What's the complement of `top -u`?

Tags: command-line, administration, top

The `top -u mary` command allows me to see all jobs running by user `mary`. 
What is the command to show the complement of that: all top processes *except* the jobs running by `mary`?

Answer (score 4):

This command will exclude all processes having `mary` as a user or process name:

```
top | grep -v mary
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to kamil's answer but doesn't exclude (hypothetical) processes named mary:

```
top | awk '$3 != "mary"'
```